# Picking images from cache after prefetching

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift2, uiimage

I'm using Kingfisher framework to prefetch images. The link to the Kingfisher framework is: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Here's my code that I've written:

```
func downloadImages() {
    if(self.albumImagePathArray.isEmpty == false) {
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            let urls = self.albumImagePathArray.map { NSURL(string: $0)! }
            let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: urls, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: {
                (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
                print("These resources are prefetched: \(completedResources)")
            })
        prefetcher.start()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to use this framework as I'm quite new to App development. Once I have prefetched the images, how do I get these prefetched images from cache. I want to pick these images from cache and put them into an array of UIImage. Previously I was not picking from cache, but I was loading the URLs every time and putting them an array of strings called albumImagePathArray and through contentsOfURL I was converting it into UIImage so it can be put into albumImages as shown in the code below:

```
var albumImages = [UIImage]()
for i in 0 ..< self.albumImagePathArray.count 
{
   let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.albumImagePathArray[i])!)!)
   self.albumImages.append(image!)
}
```

Now I want to change all that, I want to pick directly from cache after prefetching so I don't have to download the images every time which takes lot of time. Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new at iOS Dev and I'm using kingfisher for storring images to cache.

To get into the point while you prefetch the images there is an `optionInfo` which you leave it `nil`. So if i guess right you prefetch images from URLs, so in this `optionInfo` you can set a Cache Identifier for each image, and would be best if you put there the URL of the image.

Kingfisher documentation is pretty clear about the `optionInfo` so you could change your function to this

```
func downloadImages() {

    if(self.albumImagePathArray.isEmpty == false) {
        let myCache = ImageCache(name: "the url of the images")
//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            let urls = self.albumImagePathArray.map { NSURL(string: $0)! }
            let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: urls, optionsInfo: [.TargetCache(myCache)], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: {
                (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
                print("These resources are prefetched: \(completedResources)")
            })
        prefetcher.start()
    }
}
```

So with this practise you can store them to Cache. To continue you have to show us what you have tried after the prefetch.