# How to write images as NSData to Realm from Kingfisher?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, kingfisher

I do app in `swift 2.3` with `Realm database` and `Kingfisher framework` to get images.
I get images from server by `JSON`

```
let urls = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newsRealm.newsImage)
let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: [urls], optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: {
(skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
print("These resources are prefetched: \(completedResources)")
})
prefetcher.start()
```

It' is successful, but images in `Realm database` is `NSData`, how to write received data from `Kingfisher` to `Realm` as `NSData`

Realm class:

```
class News: Object {
  dynamic var newsImage: String = ""
  dynamic var images: NSData?
}
```

Hi! I cant write my images to my database i do:

```
let urls = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newsRealm.newsImage)
let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: [urls], optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler:
{(skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
print("These resources are prefetched: (completedResources.description)")
let images: [NSData] = completedResources
newsRealm.images = images
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `optionsInfo: [.TargetCache(myCache)]` to setup cache url, where you can retrieve the data (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38914515/1979882)),
or use an [example](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/8773312ed79c481b0c62769f1307889e50afdb47/Tests/KingfisherTests/KingfisherManagerTests.swift#L6) `retrieveImage`
 to retrieve `UIImage` which can be converted to `NSData` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32297704/1979882).

Comment: Hi! I cant write my images to my database i do:  let urls = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newsRealm.newsImage)
            
            let prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: [urls], optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: {
                (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
                print("These resources are prefetched: \(completedResources.description)")
                let images: [NSData] = completedResources
                newsRealm.images = images

Answer (score 0):

`completedResources` isn't an array of `NSData`. `completedResources` is an array of `Resource`. `Resource` holds `cacheKey` and `downloadURL`. You should retrieve image using `cacheKey` from the cache, then convert the image to `NSData`. Then store the data to Realm.

```
let images: [NSData] = completedResources.map { (resource) -> NSData in
    let image = ImageCache.default.retrieveImageInDiskCache(forKey: resource.cacheKey)!
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
}
```